# Error when booting from usb

Tags: boot, 20.04

I'm all new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, I recently wanted to try it without messing with my laptop, so I followed this tutorial: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview
I followed it and it worked fine, so I restarted my computer and booted from the usb but I get a error:

Failed to load ldlinux.c32
Boot failed: please change disks and press a key to continue.

I tried googling it and found some people asking for the same error and I tried the soultions they used but no luck.
I tried using Universal USB Installer insted of Rufus but it gives me another error, first is:
Unknown keyword in configuration file TCicada

and second is simply boot error and then my laptop boots into Windows 10 normally.

Help pls!!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: The latest one (20.04.1 lts)

Comment: Did you verify your ISO?  (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) ;  fyi:  Ubuntu 20.10 or the 2020-October release is a later release than Ubuntu 20.04 (or 2020-April release, even the 20.04.1 re-spin which was in August); avoid terms like *latest* esp. if inaccurate (*latest LTS* maybe what you meant)

Comment: I didn't I will try now, and to be more exact I meant the latest LTS version, I hope that doesn't make a lot of confusion.

Comment: Did you select FAT16 with Rufus? This should solve the isuue you're facing

Comment: I tried verifying but seems like verifying failed, and FAT16 isn't an option in Rufus. NTFS simply doesn't work as well